# Prove that a constraints system is a manifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, proof-writing, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

What shown to follow is a theorem taken from the text *Analysis on Manifolds* written by James Munkres.

[image: example link]

So at the page 11 of [this](https://www.quantsummaries.com/munkres.pdf) document, if you like you can read the proof of the mentioned theorem.

Now more generally I ask if this result holds.

> **Conjecture**
>
> Let $A$ be open in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$ and let be $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ be of class $C^r$. Let $M$ be the set of all $x$ such that
> $$
> f_1(x)=0,...,f_{n-(h+1)}(x)=0,f_{n-h}(x)>0,...,f_{n-i}(x)=0,....,f_n(x)>0
> $$
> for any $i=1,...,h$ and assume that $M$ is not empty and that $Df$ has rank $(n-h)$ on $M$. Then $M$ is a $k+h$ manifold without boundary in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$. Furthermore if $N$ is the set of all $x$ for which
> $$
> f_1(x)=0,...,f_{n-(h+1)}(x)=0,f_{n-h}(x)\ge 0,...,f_n(x)\ge 0
> $$
> and if the $Df$ has rank $n+(h-1)$ at each poin of $N$, then $N$ is a $k+(h+1)$ manifold and $\partial N=M$.

So substantially I ask when the solutions set of the constraint system
$$
\begin{cases}f_1(x)=0\\
\vdots\\
f_{n-(h+1)}(x)=0\\
f_{n-h}(x)\ge 0\\
\vdots\\
f_n(x)\ge 0\end{cases}
$$
is a $k+(h+1)$ manifold.

So is my conjecture true? And if it is true how prove it?

Comment: Won't this be a manifold with boundary even in many of the simplest cases? Consider e.g. $f(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with $f(\mathbf{x})=x_0$, where $\mathbf{x}=\langle x_0, x_1\rangle$. Then $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ is a boundary-less $\mathbb{R}$, whereas $f(\mathbf{x})\geq 0$ has $x_0=0$ almost definitionally as its boundary.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It seems to me that the map $f$ you defined if the projection map on the first coordinate and the solution set of the inequality $$ f(x)\ge 0$$ is the set $\Bbb R^+_0\times\Bbb R$ that is a manifold with boundary the $x_1$ axis. Is incorect what I said?

Comment: I missed that you removed the 'without boundary' at the end of your conjecture and in the followup; mea culpa.

Comment: Manifolds with corners are not manifolds with boundary. I can't muster the energy to deal with your crazy subscripts.